# Magneto creating cutom order attributes not working

Tags: magento

I need to create custom order attributes. I tried below code. After run the code attribute is not displaying in `sales_flat_order` table as a new column.

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('order', 'newfield1', array(
    'type'              => 'int',
    'global'            => 0,
    'visible'           => 0,
    'required'          => 0,
    'user_defined'      => 0,
    'searchable'        => 0,
    'filterable'        => 0,
    'comparable'        => 0,
    'visible_on_front'  => 0,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
    'unique'            => 0,
    'is_configurable'   => 0,
    'default'           => 0,
));
$installer->endSetup();
```

But one record is creating under 'eav_attribute' table. But when i am trying to add values to that attribute using below code, it gives a system error;

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(200);
$order->setNewfield1('dadhuh');
$order->save();
```

> Error:
>   Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()  in C:\xampp\htdocs\abcproject\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php on line 125

Can anyone help me to solve this issue. Can anyone advice me what i did wrong here.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this .try to create a same directories on system and this will craete a new sales order attribute named as  "**customfield**"

app/code/local/Knkm/Orderattribute/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Knkm_Orderattribute>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Knkm_Orderattribute>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <orderattribute>
        <class>Knkm_Orderattribute_Helper</class>
      </orderattribute>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <orderattribute>
        <class>Knkm_Orderattribute_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>orderattribute_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </orderattribute>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <salesattribute1446018370_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Knkm_Orderattribute</module>
          <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </salesattribute1446018370_setup>
      <salesattribute1446018370_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </salesattribute1446018370_write>
      <salesattribute1446018370_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </salesattribute1446018370_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Knkm/Orderattribute/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Knkm_Orderattribute_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

/app/code/local/Knkm/Orderattribute/sql/salesattribute1446018370_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("order", "customfield", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

app/etc/modules/Knkm_Orderattribute.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Knkm_Orderattribute>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Knkm_Orderattribute>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Hope this will do your work.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
'type'          => 'varchar'
'backend_type'  => 'varchar',
'frontend_input' => 'varchar',
'is_user_defined' => true,
'label'         => 'custom_label',
'visible'      => true,
'required'      => false,
'user_defined'  => false,
'searchable'    => false,
'filterable'    => false,
'comparable'    => false,
'default'       => ''
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'custom_attribute', $attribute);
$installer->addAttribute('quote', 'custom_attribute', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();

echo 'success';
```